# Monogame, VS2010, .Net 4.5 not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, monogame

I have been building a project in Mono-game using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10. Everything works fine until i close the solution. When i attempt to reopen the solution i get an error "Project target framework not installed". The only way to continue is to re target the project to .NET 4.0 which i thought would be fine. I then try to compile the project and get this error.

The type or namespace name 'Xna' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

I have checked the references and the monogame framework is there. I also get this error.

The primary reference "MonoGame.Framework" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Comment: Start using VS2015.

Comment: Thanks, i was already downloading it. Hopefully that will work fine. I was only really using vs2010 as it was compatible with xna but since monogame works with vs2015 i don't really need it.

Comment: Yes VS2015 fixed the issue fine, must be a bug in VS2010 with Monogame.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use VS2010 anymore. The latest mainstream Visual Studio version is VS2015 but you could already use VS2017 RC. Choose also a proper .Net Framework version because some of them have reached the [end-of-life status](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3014125/security/some-versions-of-net-framework-to-be-discontinued-in-january.html).